# How to remove thin back frame around pdf page at ICEpdf?

Tags: java, pdf, javafx, javafx-2, icepdf

I'm making PDF displaying application with ICEpdf. I an trying to make some fancy layout according to good design practices. I use this code

```
System.getProperties().put("org.icepdf.core.views.background.color", "#FFFFFF");
System.getProperties().put("org.icepdf.core.views.page.border.color", "#FFFFFF");
System.getProperties().put("org.icepdf.core.views.page.shadow.color", "#FFFFFF");
```

To make background of viewer component white and to remove frame and shadow of the page. But the thin black frame around the page is still there:

[image]

Any chance to get rid of it? I want to acnieve illusion that pdf page is stretched to the size of parent container. I use swingNode inside JavaFX application (in case that have some importance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by wrappind PDF Swing component into AnchorPane and setting anchors to small negative values:

```
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(question, -5.0);
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(question, -5.0);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(question, -5.0);
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(question, -5.0);
```